# How can I let `anything-but` support `not-exist` in event pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am following this instruction https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-anything-but to setup a event pattern rule with `anything-but` like below code:

```json
{
"detail": {
    "payload": {
      "type": [
        {
          "anything-but": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In above example, I set the `type` field in `payload` of the event to be anything but `test`. It works fine if the event has `payload->type` field. But it doesn't accept the event if it payload doesn't have `type` field. It seems `anything-but` filter out `none-exist` field.

As an example, below event payload is accepted:

```json
{
  detail: {
     payload: {
       name: 'xxx',
       type: 'production'
     }
  }
}
```

but below event which doesn't have `type` field is not accepted.

```json
{
  detail: {
     payload: {
       name: 'xxx'
     }
  }
}
```

How can I let it support `none-exist`? I'd like to make it accept event who doesn't have such field.

Comment: Can you show what an example event looks like?

Comment: yes, I have added the two examples

Answer (score 1):

You have certainly moved on with your life since then... but figured I would drop an answer here for anyone else traversing the interwebs in frustration with EventBridge rules...

In the array you are assigning to `type`, you can include any number of matching options:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "payload":
      "type": [
        {"anything-but": "test"},
        {"exists": false}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you need more complex matching that includes multiple fields existing or not, look into `$or`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-complex-example-or